# Break after control statements in clang-format

Tags: c++, formatting, clang, libclang, clang-format

I'm using `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` in my `.clang-format` file, but braces in control statements (such as `if`, `for`, `while`, ...) are not being put on their own line.

```
// Currently:
void foo()
{
    while(true) {
        bar();
    }
}

// What I want:
void foo()
{
    while(true) 
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

[I've read that](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) you can set nested configuration classes for braces in `BraceWrapping`, but I could't figure out the correct YAML syntax (and JSON syntax for the sublime text plugin), and couldn't find any existing example.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: When I run `clang-format -i -style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman}" test.cpp` on your example it puts all braces on their own line as you'd expect for the Allman style. Do you see something else?

Comment: @RichardViney: you're right... I did some tests and turns out that `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true` is the culprit of this issue. Setting it to `false` makes the formatting work as intended. Is this a bug?

Comment: No I don't think this is a bug, in fact there are other style options such as `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine` which when used with `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` will also allow braces to sometimes not always have a line all to themselves under certain conditions. If you want ultra-strict Allman braces you'll need to check these other styles as well.

Comment: But, as an example, the `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine` option is `bool` and only allows `true` or `false`. And it does affect the Allman braces *(as shown in the original question)*, even when the loop isn't actually transformed in a single line.

Comment: If it does indeed do that then yes I agree it's a bug, however `clang-format -i -style="{BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true}" test.cpp` run on both LLVM 3.6.2 and on trunk don't exhibit that behaviour in my testing. Maybe there's some interaction with another style that you're using?

Comment: @RichardViney: I did more tests and figured out the combination of styles - I opened a bug report on: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25069

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achieving the desired result with a specific combination of style options is impossible at the moment. I've reported [the issue as bug 25069](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25069).

Comment: It looks like clang-format-3.8 has individual options for breaking when BraceWrapping is set to custom now.

Comment: This is still a bug as of clang-format 5.0.1.

The key combination is `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true` and any other `AllowShort...OnASingleLine` option. Having both options set seems to negate the Allman brace style. If `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false` then you can control to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this, I first run [artistic style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Brace_Style_Options) with the option `-A10`, before running clang-format